# Accessing deallocated memory with UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a little bit confused with the behavior of `UnsafeMutablePointer`.

Following piece of code is crashing as expected, because we are trying to access the memory which already has been deallocated.

```
let storage = UnsafeMutablePointer<[UInt8]>.allocate(capacity: 1)
// initialize
storage.initialize(to: [0x01])

storage.deinitialize(count: 1)
storage.deallocate()

print(storage) // 0x00007ff236404890
print(storage.pointee) // Will Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Changing the type to Bool will not crash the application and we can read the pointee value. Why is this the case?

```
let storage = UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>.allocate(capacity: 1)
// initialize
storage.initialize(to: false)

storage.deinitialize(count: 1)
storage.deallocate()

print(storage) // 0x00007ff236404890
print(storage.pointee) // false
```

Comment: Rerun the `UInt8` example a bunch. It should crash, too. Both of these are cases of undefined behavior, and what you're seeing is two different possible behaviors, neither of which are guaranteed *not* to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jckarter answered the question for me on Twitter.

So first of all it's  always good to use the address sanitizer when working with memory directly.

Accessing memory after it's deallocated is undefined behavior.
So multiple things can happen **we can not rely** on this.

The behavior for this is because of:

> When you free memory it isn't necessarily returned to the OS right
> away, since it's more efficient to leave the memory as is until it's
> needed for a new allocation. So you may be able to access an old value
> some time after the memory is freed, but you can't rely on it.
>
> Using memory checking tools like Address Sanitizer or Guard Malloc
> should make the behavior more predictable, since they add more
> checking for memory used after deallocation
>
> -- @jckarter

Description when address sanitizer enabled:

```
let storage = UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>.allocate(capacity: 1)
// initialize
storage.initialize(to: false)

storage.deinitialize(count: 1)
storage.deallocate()

print(storage) 
print(storage.pointee) // Thread 1: Use of deallocated memory ❗️
```